# use of a static method inside a Windows service to call data in webform without creating a new object

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, static-methods

I'm creating a Windows webform page and needed a background service to keep track of data even when the web app is down. I'm new to using Windows Services and have a question. will it work on a server when i call a static method from the service inside the webform page

i made it so the service keeps receiving the data. when i open the webform page i made it so the page gets the needed data in string without creating a new instance of the class that receives the data. this all works in Local IIS but my question is if it will work on a server with the service installed running 24/7 with the user still receiving all data from it on there own machine.

**Both Projects are in the same VS Solution and the Asp.net project is connected wih the Service through a reference**

ServiceBase class. Method where the data comes from:

```
    public static string LoadStatus()
    {
        //Receive data
        ...

        //Return data
        List<string> streamString = new List<string>();
        foreach (var str in InstanceStreams)
        {
            streamString.Add(str.Name + "," + str.Stream + "+");
        }
        result = String.Join("", streamString);
        return strHTMLProd + "|" + strHTMLTest + "|" + errors + "|" + result;
    }
```

Web Form page. Method that gets the data and then prints it out on screen:

```
    public void setLabel()
    {
            string[] labels = AzureMonitor.LoadStatus().Split('|');
            if (labels != null && labels.Count() == 4)
            {
                lblStatusProd.Text = labels[0];
                lblStatusTest.Text = labels[1];
                alarm = labels[2];
                array = labels[3].TrimEnd('+');
                if (array != "" && array != null)
                {
                    string[] Streams = array.Split('+');

                    ...
                }
              ...
            }
        lblUpdate.Text = "Last update: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    }
```

When i run it on server i want the returned data to never be null and to be the same as in the service class that's why i made a static method and avoided making a new Instance. 
But is it 100% save and if not is there any way to improve setting and getting data between them without making a copy of the class.

Comment: What mechanisms are you using for the communication between the webforms and the windows service? If you've *referenced* the service assembly from the web project, realise that that means you're loading into the web service's process, not accessing the service process at all.

Comment: they are both within the same solution and the asp.net project has a assembly reference to the windows service project

Comment: Then you're not really using the service. At this point it may as well have been a class library project instead. If you want a service to *run as a service*, it's going to be a separate process from the asp.net application and so you need to be using some form of IPC mechanism for the two to talk.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is it possible to keep it running and just get the data every minute or so using a reference and still let the service do its own thing apart from the Web app or do i actually need to add some sort of extra software or something else to just get data from it(even tho the service is partly ment for returning data to the web app its not the main purpose of the service and it still runs seperatly when no data will be returned to the web app). could u please explain to me what i need if you know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a Solution by adding a table to my database and store the Monitoring in it and make the web page receive the info stored in the table to use for asp:labels that then will update and show the monitoring on screen without making any connection with the two directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do.  Are these into two separate applications (a Windows service and Forms desktop application)?  If not then it is chance that it works at the moment, rather than by design.

You are using a mish-mash of different technologies.  I would suggest you might be better off putting the monitoring logic into an ASP.NET MVC application (which is hosted in the IIS service and runs all the time) and maybe use SignalR to get a realtime stream of data rather than relying on constantly polling for updates.  The desktop application can use Forms or WPF and the C# SignalR client to receive data.  Alternatively you could write a web-based client (using something like Angular) to display the data.

Comment: I too initially thought they were talking about a thick client app but on re-reading, they do use *web*form consistently. (Although I wouldn't personally recommend that flavour of ASP.NET for modern work)

Comment: its actually one solution within VS with a view different projects where 1 of them is a Asp.net Web Forms App and the other a Windows Service, The Web Form app is connected to the service with a reference leading to that project and that way i can call the return method from the windows service inside the Web Form page. the page uses a simple refresh timer to refresh the SetLabel() method and the Windows service also uses a refresh method for a view methods including the static LoadStatus() method. with the code we have we can't go from web Forms to MVC. i'll edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: If it's not very clear what he's doing, please try to use comments instead. Posting it as an answer is akin to "I don't know what you're doing, but here's how to do it".

Comment: @open-collar Can you tell me if SignalR can run on the background like a Service, get data from azure management and ADAL assembly references, get certain configuration fields from App.config or Web.config and run 24/7 ? also Thank you for the advice

Comment: I hadn't noticed you were talking about a web-based application.  In this case SignalR would operate on the client (the web page) in the background providing events when the data is received.  On the server side it is up to you how you implement the code the reads data and write it to SignalR, but you can certainly read config from the Web.config file.  However what you want to do will require a fair bit of effort from you to develop - SignalR simply provides a (relatively) simple mechanism to send messages back to the browser.